# не работает сетевой сканнер в centos 7 после последнего обновления

Tags: centos, hp, sane

прошло обновление отвалился еще и сетевой сканнер. При попытке обращения выдает следующую диагностику`

дек 21 13:04:42 x.ru saned[17904]: io/hpmud/musb.c 426: Found interface conf=0, iface=2, altset=0, index=7

дек 21 13:04:42 x.ru saned[17904]: io/hpmud/musb.c 388: Active kernel driver on interface=2 ret=0

дек 21 13:04:42 x.ru saned[17904]: io/hpmud/musb.c 531: claimed ff/ff/ff interface

дек 21 13:04:42 x.ru saned[17904]: common/utils.c 130: validate_plugin_version() Plugin version[3.13.7] mismatch with HPLIP v...[3.15.9]

дек 21 13:04:42 x.ru saned[17904]: common/utils.c 157: Plugin version is not matching

дек 21 13:04:42 x.ru saned[17904]: common/utils.c 220: Invalid Library hanlder pLibHandler = NULL.

дек 21 13:04:42 x.ru saned[17904]: io/hpmud/musb.c 557: released ff/ff/ff interface

дек 21 13:04:42 x.ru saned[17904]: io/hpmud/musb.c 971: removed HP-MARVELL-SCAN channel=21 clientCnt=0 channelCnt=0

дек 21 13:07:17 x.ru saned[17904]: saned exiting

дек 21 13:07:17 x.ru xinetd[17863]: EXIT: sane-port status=0 pid=17904 duration=174(sec`

хоть бы говорил какой плагин. Или я не вижу в диагностике его. Кто сталкивался?

Answer (score 0):

проблема решилась. ПО команде hp-plugin -i устанавливаются плагины нужной версии с сайта HP